# Tracking api calls with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `api_keys` where I track api transactions. I been give 3 api keys by provider `apiA` each key allows for a maximum of 5000 calls. I am able to run separate queries to get `total number of calls`, `api keys with < 5000 calls` and `api keys with 5000 calls`. However, how can i place those queries in to one query that displays percentage of `consumed` and `not_used`? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd91da/2)

Desired output in percentage:

```
+----------+----------+
| Consumed | Not_used |
+----------+----------+
|       70 |       30 |
+----------+----------+
```

Total number of api calls

```
SELECT COUNT(*) * 5000 as total_api_calls FROM api_keys WHERE `source` = 'apiA';
```

Api keys that havent reached 5000 calls:

```
SELECT * FROM api_keys WHERE `source` = 'apiA' and `transactions` < 5000
```

Api keys that have reached 5000 calls:

```
SELECT * FROM api_keys WHERE `source` = 'apiA' and `transactions` >= 5000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html) statements will give each row `used` and `not_used` flags set to 1 or 0 appropriately. Then you can [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) them up and divide by the total number of rows to get the percentage.

```
SELECT `source`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN transactions <  5000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*)*100 AS 'Not Used',
       SUM(CASE WHEN transactions >= 5000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(*)*100 AS 'Used'
FROM api_keys
WHERE `source` = 'apiA';
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get a `sum` of remaining api calls?

Comment: @MaryCoding I don't understand. Could you give an example?

Comment: For example there are `10,000` total api calls  but how could I display the number of available api calls left to use, `1357`.

Comment: @MaryCoding That's a whole other question, but the answer is short so I'll do it here. ``SELECT id, `source`, CASE WHEN transactions < 5000 THEN 5000 - transactions ELSE 0 END as 'Transactions Remaining' FROM api_keys;``

Comment: Great, thank you this opened doors to other possibilities.